# Php achievement system not displaying properly

Tags: php

I'm creating an achievement system for a website. When you submit your first comment you can see in a corner of the screen a message that show the name and id of the achievement, it hides after a few seconds.

That works fine except when you get two achievements in a row. It displays two messages one after another but they have the id of the first achievement on the page. If i get the achievements 5 and 8 it will show the message of the number 5 two times instead of 5 and then 8.

What should I do? Thanks.

```
$user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_SESSION['user_id']);
if (isset($user_id)){

    function notification($connection, $trophy_id){
    $trophy_sql = "SELECT * FROM trophy WHERE trophy_id = '$trophy_id'";
    $trophy_result = mysqli_query($connection, $trophy_sql);

        if ($trophy = $trophy_result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '
        <a href="../colection/achievement.php?id=' . $trophy['trophy_id'] . '">
        <div id="notification2" title="See trophy">

        <span class="trophy"><i class="fa fa-trophy ' . $trophy['trophy_color'] . '"></i></span>
        <span class="text">
        <span class="title">' . $trophy['trophy_name'] . '</span>
        <span class="subt">Text</span>
        </span><!-- title -->
        </div><!-- notification --></a>

        <script>
        $("#notification2").delay(1000).animate({width: "toggle"}).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
        </script>';
        }
    }

$number_comments_sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments_user = '$user_id' AND comments_type IS NULL AND comments_deleted IS NULL";
$number_comments_result = mysqli_query($connection, $number_comments_sql);
$number_comments = mysqli_num_rows($number_comments_result);

$number_posts_sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comments_user = '$user_id' AND comments_position = '2' AND comments_deleted IS NULL";
$number_posts_result = mysqli_query($connection, $number_posts_sql);
$number_posts = mysqli_num_rows($number_posts_result);


for ($i=0;$i<3;++$i){
switch ($i){

    case 1:

        if ($number_comments > 0){
        $achiev_sql = "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE ad_type_id = 2 AND ad_user = '$user_id'";
        $achiev_result = mysqli_query($connection, $achiev_sql);
        $achiev = mysqli_num_rows($achiev_result);
            if ($achiev == 0){
                    notification($connection, 2);   
            }
        }break;


    case 2:

        if ($number_posts > 0){
        $achiev_sql = "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE ad_type_id = 3 AND ad_user = '$user_id'";
        $achiev_result = mysqli_query($connection, $achiev_sql);
        $achiev = mysqli_num_rows($achiev_result);
            if ($achiev == 0){
                    notification($connection, 3);               
            }
        }break; 


} // for
} // switch
} // end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are querying for results,each time you are querying based on the userId,that is every time you are querying you will be getting all the comments given by the logged-in user,so if the user creates comment with id=5,then you will have a notification of the same,if the user creates  comment with id=8,then you will again get a notification for the comment whose id is 5 because even that comment was created by the same user.So instead you can have a flag for every comment if the notification has been provided or not.

Comment: The id was from achievement id. A good example would be: earn trophy_id 5 when write your first comment and trophy_id 8 if you write the first comment of the post so it's possible that your first comment is the first comment of the post aswell.

Comment: Can you please share the front end(HTML) code for submitting the comment that you are using.